# Symfony2 - Environments - Can't import routing.yml from common folder

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to create a folder structure like described in [Different Directories per Environment](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html#different-directories-per-environment):

```
- app
    - config
        - common
            - config.yml
            - routing.yml
        - dev
            - config.yml
            - routing.yml
```

This does work pretty well for all files (*config.yml*, *parameters.yml* etc.) but nor for **config.yml**.

I get this error:

> **The routing file "[…]" contains unsupported keys for "imports": "0".** Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "pattern", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition".

What I've done so far:

**appKernel.php**

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader) {
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/'.$this->getEnvironment().'/config.yml');
}
```

**routing.yml in *dev***

```
#app/config/dev/routing.yml
imports:
    - { resource: ../common/routing.yml }
```

**config.yml in *common***

```
#app/config/common/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: 'parameters.yml' }
    - { resource: 'security.yml' }
    - { resource: 'services.yml' }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/common/routing.yml"
```

**config.yml in *dev***

```
#app/config/dev/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: '../common/config.yml' }
    - { resource: 'parameters.yml' }
    - { resource: 'security.yml' }
    - { resource: 'services.yml' }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/dev/routing.yml"
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: did you change the code of the registerContainerConfiguration() method ?

Comment: @Freelancer Yes, I did. I've added the code to the question.

Comment: in your config.yml why are you not importing the parameters.yml and security.yml ?

Comment: @Freelancer Actually I do. I just removed it to make the question shorter - I've added the whole thing now.

Comment: why not calling directly routing.yml from common in your app/config/dev/config.yml instead of creating a routing.yml that import the file from common ?

Comment: @Freelancer Maybe I'm thinking the wrong way. The `routing.yml` is imported by `framework[router][resource]`. I thought I have to overwrite this setting with the `routing.yml` in *dev*. As all other routes would be missing then, I thought re-import all routes from **common** would merge the common and dev routes.

Comment: the error message implies there is something wrong with the routing.yml file.  Can you check the spacing as all indents need to have 4 spaces.  If one subitem is indented 11 spaces when there should be 12, the loadng will fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got it running. I have set the new routing file in my *dev config*:

```
#app/config/dev/config.yml
framework:
    # update routing
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/dev/routing.yml"
```

And I imported the *common routing* in the *dev routing* by not using `imports: - { resource: ../common/routing.yml }` but this instead:

```
#app/config/dev/routing.yml
_common:
    resource: ../common/routing.yml
```

Works like a charm. It seems that the `import` directive is not allowed in the `routing.yml`.

Comment: Indeed. And if you have many files to import, this will do:

```
routes_front:
  resource: "routes_front.yaml"

routes_back:
  resource: "routes_back.yaml"

routes_api:
  resource: "routes_api.yaml"
  
routes_script:
  resource: "routes_script.yaml"
```